# Using find command with recursive copy without -r or a while/for loop

Tags: linux, find, cp

I have the following problem. Normally one would use the command find exec cp -r to copy everything from one directory to another. In this case I am not allowed to do so, or use a while/for loop for the find command.

What I need it to do is copy everything from one directory to another with the complete directory structure.

Comment: Why do you need `find` for that?

Comment: Because my teacher told me so haha. But googling gives no results.

Comment: You can use `rsync -r`

Comment: I know, but we may not use something different then find...

Comment: you can use `ls -R` to list your directories recursively and pipe the result to a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with something like this:

```
src=/home/user
dst=/to/dir
find -exec printf " echo {} | \
        sed 's|^$src|$dst|;s|/[^/]*$||' | \
        xargs -n1 -I@ mkdir -p @\n" \; | \
   sh
```

which creates the directory structure under destination directory. You can add many commands to printf.

Comment: i wish people did my homework for me when i was in school

Comment: this is far from complete though